# Music Duration counter view

Tags: readability, counter, music

I 'm working on a android application, this app may list your songs.
so the developers put the default counter as singular digit like ""0:4:0 ""

is it better to display it as a double digit format like "00:04:00" ?
is it more readable in that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. I would prefer `00:00:00` variation because people are used to write time in this format so it is more visual.

Comment: yea, i though that too, it more readable than the singular format